# Fazendo buscas e comparação java

Tags: java, array

Estou elaborando um programa que deve solicitar o RA de um aluno, o RA deve ser maior que zero. Logo após quero comprar o segundo RA digitado para verificar se o mesmo já não foi cadastrado. elaborei o código abaixo mas ele continua deixando eu cadastrar números repetidos.

```
  if (nroAlunos == ra.length) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não há mais espaço para cadastro.");} 
 for (int i = 0; i < ra.length; i++) {
    int cadastroRa = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o RA que deseja cadastrar:"));
    if (cadastroRa == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O número deve ser maior que zero...");
    } else {                            
            if (cadastroRa == ra[i]) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O RA digitado já esta cadastrado.");
            } else {
                ra[i] = cadastroRa;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RA " + cadastroRa + " cadastrado com sucesso.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tem alguns problemas na sua abordagem: e se o vetor já estiver todo preenchido? Vai salvar por cima de algum ra existente? Outra coisa, toda iteração que o if for falso, ele vai salvar o ra.

Comment: Acima do for eu tenho um if para validação caso o array esteja totalmente preenchido.

Comment: Então adicione na pergunta. Eu estou tentando elaborar uma sugestão, mas com partes faltando fica complicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um simples break até resolveria o problema, mas seu código tem outros vários que eu relatei nos comentários. Diante disto, gostaria de sugerir uma abordagem diferente, que resolve o problema de repetidos e outros que o código possui:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] ra = new int[10];

    int indice = 0;

    boolean cadastrado = false;

    do {

        int cadastroRa = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o RA que deseja cadastrar:"));

        if (cadastroRa <= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O número deve ser maior que zero...");
        } else if (existe(cadastroRa, ra)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O RA digitado já esta cadastrado.");
        } else if (indice < ra.length){

            ra[indice] = cadastroRa;
            indice++;
            cadastrado = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RA " + cadastroRa + " cadastrado com sucesso.");

        }

    } while (!cadastrado);

}

public static boolean existe(int cadastroRa, int[] listaRa) {

    boolean existe = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < listaRa.length; i++) {

        if (cadastroRa == listaRa[i]) {
            existe = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return existe;
}
```

Veja que o método `existe()` tem como unica finalidade checar se o valor já existe no array, e retorna true ou false se for encontrado.

Já o cadastro no array, o controle é feito pela variavel `indice`, assim se evita de preencher um valor do array já preenchido ou uma posição maior que o tamanho do array.

Comment: Eu não havia estudado a possibilidade da criação de um método para isso, acreditava que poderia realizar a validação  somente no if. Ajudou muito cara, Obrigado.

Comment: @P.Pires claro que pode e deve! Isso ajuda a organizar melhor seu código, além de separar responsabilidades =)

Comment: Com certeza, economizou alguma linhas.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Arrays.stream(ra).anyMatch(xh -> xh == cadastroRa))
```

Seu código final ficará assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ra.length; i++) {
    int cadastroRa = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o RA que deseja cadastrar:"));

    if (cadastroRa == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O número deve ser maior que zero...");
    } else {                            
        if (Arrays.stream(ra).anyMatch(xh -> xh == cadastroRa)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O RA digitado já esta cadastrado.");
        } else {
            ra[i] = cadastroRa;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RA " + cadastroRa + " cadastrado com sucesso.");
        }
    }
}
```